# Groupby DataFrame - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I manipulate the dataframe so I can group by the item so that the item is not repeating in all the rows?  The output has to be in a dataframe.

I been stuck on this all night and am completely stuck.

Input

```
Date            Item    Units_Sold      Store   Holiday 
2017-01-01      Apple       8           1       Yes    
2017-01-01      Pear        4           1       Yes
2017-01-02      Apple       3           1       No
2017-01-02      Pear        3           1       No
2017-01-03      Apple       8           1       Yes
2017-01-03      Pear        9           1       Yes
```

Output

```
Item             Units_Sold       Store      Holiday              
Apple              
  2017-01-01     8                1          Yes   
  2017-01-02     3                1          No
  2017-01-03     8                1          Yes                                      
Pear
  2017-01-01     4                1          Yes
  2017-01-02     3                1          No
  2017-01-03     9                1          Yes
```

Comment: You need to add your code. I'm not even really sure what you are trying to achieve. What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: like the second part of the coded out part in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can create `dict of DataFrames`:

```
dfs = {i:x.drop('Item',1) for i, x in df.groupby('Item')}
print (dfs)
{'Pear':          Date  Units_Sold  Store Holiday
1  2017-01-01           4      1     Yes
3  2017-01-02           3      1      No
5  2017-01-03           9      1     Yes, 'Apple':          Date  Units_Sold  Store Holiday
0  2017-01-01           8      1     Yes
2  2017-01-02           3      1      No
4  2017-01-03           8      1     Yes}
```

And then select by `key`:

```
print (type(dfs['Apple']))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print (dfs['Apple'])
         Date  Units_Sold  Store Holiday
0  2017-01-01           8      1     Yes
2  2017-01-02           3      1      No
4  2017-01-03           8      1     Yes

print (dfs['Pear'])
         Date  Units_Sold  Store Holiday
1  2017-01-01           4      1     Yes
3  2017-01-02           3      1      No
5  2017-01-03           9      1     Yes
```

### ---

Or create `DataFrame with MultiIndex` :

```
df1 = df.set_index('Item', append=True)
print (df1)
               Date  Units_Sold  Store Holiday
  Item                                        
0 Apple  2017-01-01           8      1     Yes
1 Pear   2017-01-01           4      1     Yes
2 Apple  2017-01-02           3      1      No
3 Pear   2017-01-02           3      1      No
4 Apple  2017-01-03           8      1     Yes
5 Pear   2017-01-03           9      1     Yes
```

And select by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (df1.xs('Apple', level=1))
         Date  Units_Sold  Store Holiday
0  2017-01-01           8      1     Yes
2  2017-01-02           3      1      No
4  2017-01-03           8      1     Yes

print (df1.xs('Pear', level=1))
         Date  Units_Sold  Store Holiday
1  2017-01-01           4      1     Yes
3  2017-01-02           3      1      No
5  2017-01-03           9      1     Yes
```

A bit improved solution with [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.swaplevel.html) and [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Item', append=True).swaplevel(0,1).sort_index()
print (df1)
               Date  Units_Sold  Store Holiday
Item                                          
Apple 0  2017-01-01           8      1     Yes
      2  2017-01-02           3      1      No
      4  2017-01-03           8      1     Yes
Pear  1  2017-01-01           4      1     Yes
      3  2017-01-02           3      1      No
      5  2017-01-03           9      1     Yes

print (df1.xs('Apple'))
         Date  Units_Sold  Store Holiday
0  2017-01-01           8      1     Yes
2  2017-01-02           3      1      No
4  2017-01-03           8      1     Yes

print (df1.xs('Pear'))
         Date  Units_Sold  Store Holiday
1  2017-01-01           4      1     Yes
3  2017-01-02           3      1      No
5  2017-01-03           9      1     Yes
```